# I'm making building schematics (i.e. artboards) of all the building essentials on our two story school and church. Can I stack these like a book?

Tags: artboard

I am making artboards using the schematic drawings I have our our LARGE TWO story church and school. I am making separate artboards for all of the church campuses essentials like: Mechanicals, electricals, security, safety, plumbing etc. I have the various (separate) artboards made up. Now I would like to 'stack them' (on top of each other) (like a book), while being to able to SEE THROUGH all the layered artboards at one time...or to be able to 'flip' the artboards like a book.

Comment: Hi Robert. You kind of need to explain what software you may be using. Artboards are a feature in a few different application. Please [edit the question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/162732/edit) to detail the software you are referring to. And, as far as I'm aware, no app offers any ability to "flip through artboards like a book". You generally need an app designed more for layout than drawing, such as InDesign or XPress, which have "Pages" as opposed to "Artboards".